# How to have my subtitle change in ggplot based on the event chosen

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

So right now I am bringing back data from live basketball games being played. I am showing the live line as the game moves along, so I am only showing the favorite. I wish to show the team that is the favorite in the game. I have already filtered out the underdog and only have the favorite left, but can't figure out the best way to show which team is the favorite in my plot because I am filtering my line chart on the event name (the name of the game, which has both teams). I am using shiny to make it interactive, so I was wondering if I could figure out a way to change my subtitle (currently subtitle = "Game Spead") to be the name of the favorite.

[Picture of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWfAm.png)

So currently when the server is run - I can choose in a dropdown based on the event and the line charts autopopulate. I wish for the subtitle to change so it will show the favorite (or which team's lines I am looking at)

```
server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  #load data
  df3 = read.csv(paste0("C:/Users/Ethan Altmayer/Desktop/Gambling Data/R Analysis/Consolidated_Data_",Sys.Date()-1,".csv"))
  
  #summarize data
  data = reactive({
    req(input$Event)
    df3 <- filter(df3, Side == "Favorite")
    df3 <- df3 %>% filter(Event %in% input$Event)
  })
  
  #select list dynamically
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "Event", choices = df3$Event)
  })
  
  #plot
  output$plot = renderPlot({
      g = ggplot(data(), aes(x=Time.Remaining)) +
      
      geom_line(size = 1, aes(y=Original.Line, color = "#69b3a2")) +
        geom_point(color="orchid", size = 2, aes(y=Live.Line)) +
      geom_line(size = 1, aes(y=Live.Line, color = "steelblue")) +
      labs(title = "Live Line vs Original",
           subtitle = "Game Spead",
           y = "Line", x = "Time Remaining") +
      facet_wrap(~ Half) + 
      scale_x_reverse() +
        scale_color_discrete(name = "Line Type", labels = c("Original Line", "Live Line")) +
        theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "Snow"))
      print(g)
  })
  
}  

ui = basicPage(
  h1("Game"),
  selectInput(inputId = "Event", 
        label = "Choose Game", "Names"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In which variable is stored the name of team?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow alty1723! It would greatly help if you could share your data (or at least a dataset with similar features as the one you use in your work). This way, your potential helpers will be able to run your code and find a solution for you.

Comment: The variable name is "Team". I'll add a screenshot of my data above

Comment: Try adding this in `labs`: `subtitle = unique(data()$Team)`

Comment: That worked! Thank you. How do I mark your answer as solved?

Comment: @alty1723 Hi dear, I have added the code as solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Next code can be useful:

```
server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  #load data
  df3 = read.csv(paste0("C:/Users/Ethan Altmayer/Desktop/Gambling Data/R Analysis/Consolidated_Data_",Sys.Date()-1,".csv"))
  
  #summarize data
  data = reactive({
    req(input$Event)
    df3 <- filter(df3, Side == "Favorite")
    df3 <- df3 %>% filter(Event %in% input$Event)
  })
  
  #select list dynamically
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "Event", choices = df3$Event)
  })
  
  #plot
  output$plot = renderPlot({
      g = ggplot(data(), aes(x=Time.Remaining)) +
      
      geom_line(size = 1, aes(y=Original.Line, color = "#69b3a2")) +
        geom_point(color="orchid", size = 2, aes(y=Live.Line)) +
      geom_line(size = 1, aes(y=Live.Line, color = "steelblue")) +
      labs(title = "Live Line vs Original",
           subtitle = unique(data()$Team),
           y = "Line", x = "Time Remaining") +
      facet_wrap(~ Half) + 
      scale_x_reverse() +
        scale_color_discrete(name = "Line Type", labels = c("Original Line", "Live Line")) +
        theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "Snow"))
      print(g)
  })
  
}  

ui = basicPage(
  h1("Game"),
  selectInput(inputId = "Event", 
        label = "Choose Game", "Names"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```